# Nats server (Gnats)

Tags: golang

Можно ли паблишить сообщения в топик на сервере если он заембежен в код:

```
server := RunServer(&DefaultOptions)
defer server.Shutdown()
//url := fmt.Sprintf("nats://%s:%d", opts.Host, opts.Port)
nc, _ := nats.Connect(nats.DefaultURL)
// Simple Async Subscriber
nc.Subscribe("foo", func(m *nats.Msg) {
    fmt.Printf("Received a message: %s\n", string(m.Data))
})
//метода Publish нету у сервера.
server.Publish("foo", []byte("data"))
```

Не хочу создавать киента для сервера. Напрямую быстрее бы работало.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, публичного интерфейса нет. Да и разница не будет заметна.